# Choose a note in Preview PDF

Tags: preview

I just move from a Windows user to a Mac user.  I have a problem selecting a (yellow) note in Preview for Mac OS Mojave.  I want to click a note and then delete it.

However, when I click on a note, two things RANDOMLY happen.  The note is selected with a gray rectangle, which is what I want.  The second thing is that the note is open, which occurs more often.  I try to press the Esc key to close it, but it doesn't close.  In this case, I have to click somewhere else and try again.

I'm so confused for this simple action.  What did I do wrong?  What should I do to choose a note/annotation without opening it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed an unintuitive situation. To delete the note:

1. Right-click the note. This can be done with the mouse or by tapping with two fingers on a trackpad.
2. The note will highlight and a menu will show up. Click anywhere outside the menu to get rid of the menu. Now the note has a gray outline.
3. Click Edit > Delete at the menu bar.

Here is a GIF of the process. Note the first click is a right-click. [image: here is a GIF of the process]